# Return a 'raw' response with FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm in a bit of a pickle and I hope one of the more advanced Symfony / FOSRestBundle users can help me out with this.

FOSRestBundle returns responses as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <result>
  <entry>
  </entry>
 </result>
```

The thing is, I am storing complete XML blobs in my database because some other systems depend on it, which are as follows:

```
<profile updated="2015-03-04T10:00">
 <first_name>Peter</first_name>
 <last_name>Pan</last_name>
 <age>34</age>
 <department>Marketing</department>
 <job>Lead Marketing</job>
 <town>New York</town>
 <phone type="work">12345678910</phone>
 <email type="work">user@town.org</email>
</profile>
```

I store these as complete blobs, is there any way I can return these without having FOSRestBundle add the aforementioned stuff around my own XML?

If anything is unclear feel free to ask me for more information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try not using the `View` object and just return a `Response` with the content set to your XML and the content type to `application/xml`.

Comment: That certainly works! Thank you! I'm just curious if this is the best/nicest approach possible though?

Comment: Best would be what works and is clean. Possibly the "nicest" approach would be to work your coding completely around the `FOSRestBundle` but then you would be quite dependent on it and seems like it would require a bunch of unnecessary work. You're still working with a simple `Response` object so it's pretty clean as it is, you could always make a service that generated this for you from the given `XML` code but that depends on your preference and how much you would reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment you could send a response object with the content set to the XML and with the content type set to `application/xml` like..

```
/** @var XMLModelInterface $xmlModel */
/* $xmlModel populated from your database */
$xmlModel = new XMLModel();

$response = new Response(
    $xmlModel->getContent(),
    Response::HTTP_OK,
    array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/xml',
    )
);
```

But to add to that, what you could do is set an event listener that listened for the [`kernel.view`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-view-event) (**Typical Purposes**: Transform a non-Response return value from a controller into a Response) and convert your `XMLModelInterface` to a response. This would mean that you would only need to return an `XMLModelInterface` from your controller and you would only have one place to update if you wanted to change the way the response was handled.

I haven't tested this so it might not be bang on correct but as far as I know it would work. I've used some info from [`FOSRestBundle`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/EventListener/ViewResponseListener.php#L59-L139) and the [`SensionFrameworkExtraBundle`](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/EventListener/TemplateListener.php#L84-L134) so it should be alright.

<kbd>Event Subscriber</kbd>

```
class XMLModelResponseSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * Converts a returned XMLModelInterface to a Response object
     *
     * @param GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelView(GetResponseForControllerResultEvent $event)
    {
        // If controller result is not a XMLModelInterface ignore
        if (!is_a($event->getControllerResult(), 'Acme/SomeBundle/Model/XMLModelInterface')) {
            return;
        }

        $response = new Response(
            $event->getControllerResult()->getContent(),
            Response::HTTP_OK,
            array(
                'Content-Type' => 'application/xml',
            )
        );

        $event->setControllerResult($response);
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            KernelEvents::VIEW => 'onKernelView',
        );
    }
}
```

<kbd>Services.yml</kbd>

```
services:
    acme.subscriber.xml_model_response:
        class: Acme\SomeBundle\EventSubscriber\XMLModelResponseSubscriber
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Then in your controller you would just do..

```
/** @var XMLModelInterface $xmlModel */
/* $xmlModel populated from your database */
$xmlModel = new XMLModel();

return $xmlModel;
```